# Not able to upload files in comfortable mexican sofa cms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I try to upload an image, I get the following error:

> NoMethodError in CmsAdmin::FilesController#create undefined method
>   `match' for nil:NilClass

any solutions..?

Comment: It's probably blowing up inside Paperclip for some reason. What version you have installed? (check Gemfile.lock)

Comment: There's no `match` method in that controller. Post stack trace.